# How to write a function that controls the data end decide if a data type exists?

Tags: function, haskell

I was wondering are we able to control a data type and decide whether the entered data exists in Haskell?

For example:

```
  data Ruler    =Ruler Length Price deriving(Eq,Show)
  data Wallet =   Wallet Colour Ruler [Pencil] deriving(Eq,Show)
  data Pencil     =Pencil Penciltype Colour Price deriving(Eq,Show)
  data Colour     =Black | Blue | Green | Red deriving(Eq,Show)
  data Penciltype  =Leadpencil | Pen | Fountainpen | Feltpen deriving(Eq,Show)
  type Price     =Double
  type Length     =Int
```

So any ideas?

I want to define a function like that:

```
   isRulerAvailable :: Wallet-> Bool
        if Ruler is Available in Wallet then True
          else False
```

Comment: Can you edit the code in your question so it is valid Haskell code please. If your `AMap` type is defined how I guess you mean it to be defined, every `AMap` value must contain exactly one `Work` value, and your question then doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Did you mean to have the keyword `data` at the beginning of the first four lines?

Comment: Ok i edited.Sorry for the first one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how data types work in Haskell.

What your `wallet` data type says is

> I will store exactly one Ruler, Colour, and some Pencils under the tag Wallet.

This means that `Wallet` has only 1 `Ruler` in it and can only ever have 1 `Ruler` in it.

If you wanted to allow the possibility of not storing a `Ruler` then you'd use `Maybe Ruler` in your data declaration, not just `Ruler`.

Then your function becomes:

```
isRulerAvailable (Wallet _ ruler _) = isJust ruler
```

Which requires you to `import Data.Maybe`.

For an explanation of `Maybe`, you can look [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maybe)

Comment: so if i define it as maybe ruler then i should enter a maybe value which is Nothing or Just a.So when i give a Nothing it returns False which is ok but how can i make it return True.

Comment: isJust just returns true for the Just case and False for the Nothing case, which is exactly what you want